# How can I specify an SLDS icon for the icon attribute of QuickAction

Tags: lightning, metadata, slds, quickaction

Are the SLDS icons exposed as static resources (without a manual upload)?

Is there a syntax for referencing the the SLDS icons, as static resources, from metadata?

I am creating a QuickAction using the following metadata:

```
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>Some Feature</label>
    <lightningComponent>SomeComponent</lightningComponent>
    <type>LightningComponent</type>
    <icon>action:approval</icon>
</QuickAction>
```

I would like to set the icon to one of these: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons

This cannot be applied to the org though, and raises the error:

```
In field: Icon - no StaticResource named action:approval found
```

This makes sense, because the docs state that this attribute should refer to a static resource: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickaction.htm

I could upload the SLDS to the org as a static resource, but this seems overkill seeing as these icons are already in the system and appearing elsewhere. Additionally, if I upload the SLDS as a resource then we need keep the version in sync.

**Are the SLDS icons exposed as static resources (without a manual upload)?**

**Is there a syntax for referencing the the SLDS icons exposed as static resources from metadata?**